# Irrelevant iOS Team Agent License Agreement message

Tags: ios, code-signing, iphone-developer-program

I am a member of two development teams in the Developer Portal. One team is no longer in existence and is not being maintained by the team's "Agent".

Now herein lies my problem. I am trying to refresh my provisioning profiles in Xcode, but continually get a message telling me to have the team agent for the non-existent team to agree to current terms. Again, that team is no longer active, the developer no longer works for the company, etc., etc.

On the other hand, the team for which I am trying to do work has all agreements current. Is there any workaround for getting past this message then?

[image]

Comment: do you have any provisioning profiles from the old team that you can delete?

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Yes, I did actually try this. I deleted profiles from within Xcode and the Portal, but it still exhibited the same symptom.

Comment: Drat, hoped it was something that dumb, so easy to overlook the dumb stuff sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your Apple ID is associated with more than one developer account.  The refresh operation first hits the developer portal and runs refresh on each developer program that it finds you associated with.  Unfortunately, if the un-maintained account lists first then it will fail the entire refresh operation.

Now given that the agent is not maintaining the program, I'd hazard a guess that getting in touch with that individual to remove you from the program is also off the table.  Your next best bet is to contact Apple Developer Support and let them know that the Team Agent is not reachable and as a result you are unable to remove yourself from that un-maintained account which is causing you pain when it comes to Xcode Organizer operations.  Once you get removed from that account, that should resolve the problem with the refresh operation as it will then only find your single maintained account to refresh.  It would also be a good idea to remove any stray Certificates and Provisioning Profiles associated with the unmaintained account so that Xcode doesn't have an opportunity to spaz over not being authorized for the un-maintained account.

In the interim, your only option is to use the Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles tool to download provisioning profiles manually.  When you download new files, take an extra moment to delete the old ones to minimize confusion between older and newer versions of the profiles.